# How to create a world map with enlarged some small areas with r

Tags: r, world-map

Thank you for your kind interest.

I am trying to plot a world map with small enlarged areas (e.g., the Caribbean, Balkan peninsula, et.al). It is easy to plot a world map, but it is difficult for me to draw a figure similar to the one below. Is there any method to draw figures like the one below? Or can you please introduce me a software that can draw a similar figure?

[Please find the figure example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9czSq.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you use `ggplot`, you can specify `xlim` and `ylim` in the coordinates.

```
library(ggplot2)
usa <- map_data("usa")

ggplot() + geom_polygon(data = usa, aes(x=long, y = lat, group = group)) + 
  coord_fixed(1.3)

ggplot() + geom_polygon(data = usa, aes(x=long, y = lat, group = group)) + 
  coord_fixed(1.3, xlim = c(-110, -80), ylim = c(30, 50))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, JACKY88, thank you very much for your kind help. The figure I want to create is a world map with some enlarged little islands or areas. We can use coord_fixed to zoom some little islands or regions and combine them with a world map, however, this method is difficult to build another figure with different contents.